# setcookie() from localhost for other local site with domain name

Tags: php, cookies, drupal, xenforo

I have two site on my Linux installation :
theming.dev
xenforo.dev

On theming.dev, inside my code, I have :

```
setcookie("mycookiename", "cookievalue", time()+3600, "", "xenforo.dev");
```

But when I going on my local website called xenforo.dev, I don't have the cookie called "mycookiename", Why please ?

Note: setcookie() return true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers respect the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), which prevents a website from setting cookies on other domain names.